# Vuforia video playback with fixed dimension

Tags: vuforia

I am using vuforia video playback demo with cloud recognition.
I have combined both projects and it is working properly. But currently video dimension is according to detected object. But i need fixed width and    height when video plays.
Can anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am also getting same issue. any one have solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently Vuforia fixes the width and height at the start of the game no matter what the size of the object is. I could not find when exactly this operation is conducted but it is done at beginning of your game. When you change the size of the `ImageTarget` in runtime it is not fixed anymore. Add these lines to your `OnTrackingFound` function of `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs`

```
    if (this.name == "WhateverTheNameOfYourRelatedImageTarget"&& !isScaled)
    {   
        //Increase the size however you want i just added 1 to each dimension
        this.transform.localScale += Vector3.one;

        // make isScaled true not to scale every time it is found initially it shoud be false
        isScaled = true;
    }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What i usually do is , instead of Videoplayback , i play the video on canvas object and hook this object to `Defaulttrackableeventhandler` script. So when target is found, `gameobject.setactive(true)` and `gameobject.setactive(false)` when target is lost. By this method the size of the gameobject is fixed and it stays in a fixed location . 
I just made an example you can get [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5ccem8bl21n4ac/VideoExample.unitypackage?dl=0) (have to import it to any project and open the scene Assets/VideoExample/Examples). You can see there a bit clearer what the ScreenSpace - Overlay does ... it might be better to just switch to ScreenSpace - Camera in general

Comment: Thanks . But i am not unity developer. I'm using vuforia native android sdk .